# How would I use an array to print an image?

Tags: c, arrays, image, unsigned, ppm

I am trying to figure out how I would print a box of concentric squares using an array, which looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMJwb.jpg

I have a table of the RGB values for each color, but I am not sure how to go about this. This is what I have so far. This is exported to a PPM file format after compiling.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define HEIGHT 700
#define WIDTH 700
#define COLORS 3

int main(){
 int x,y,i;
 unsigned char image[WIDTH][HEIGHT][COLORS];
 image[][][COLORS]={{0},{0},{0,1,2}};
 printf("P6\r\n");
 printf("700 700\r\n");
 printf("255\n");
for(y=0;y<HEIGHT;++y)
{
 for(x=0;x<WIDTH;++x)
 {
  image[700][700][0];
  image[700][700][1];
  image[700][700][2];
  printf
 }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to take an array of RGB's and output an image file or are you trying to find a way to display an array image to the screen?

Comment: Output an image file that I can open with a ppm viewer

Comment: You will need to get familiar with the PPM file format and compression (if any). Once you have the array, you can use `fopen()` to create an output file and write the array in the correct format using `fwrite()`. It looks like you are using `printf()` to print the format but it needs to write to a file instead of to the console. Open a file handle and use `fprintf()` instead.

Comment: You might want to start with something simpler, like an all blue image, just to make sure that the file format is going to work.

Answer (score 0):

put this before the `printf()` calls:

```
FILE * outputFile = fopen("path/to/output/file.ppm","w");
```

Then, change all of your `printf("text")` calls to `fprintf(outputFile,"text")`

Finally, instead of using the nested loops, you can write all of the data in one call using `fwrite()`

Replace both of the loops with this:

```
fwrite((void*)image, COLORS, WIDTH * HEIGHT, outputFile);
```

this will write the array to the outputFile in 1 RGB Pixel chunks. The void* cast should silence any warnings. The image array is actually a pointer. There may be some issues with endianness but test this code and see if it works.